# Lightbox video Gallery for Bootstrap not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 4 for a website which includes an image gallery and video gallery. I'm pulling some sourcing from http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery for the lightbox work.

I've implemented the css and the jQuery script at the bottom of my body. The image gallery works perfectly so I know the implementation seems to be okay. However, when I input the html for the video gallery, the modal box appears on click, but no video runs. This is true even with their default videos listed on the website.

Should look like this:

[image]

With this default code:

```
<a href="http://youtu.be/iQ4D273C7Ac" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos" class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/iQ4D273C7Ac/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
</a>
```

And here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Band Homepage" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Syncopate:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-style.css">

    <title>Truth Takes Time</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!--navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Truth Takes Time</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">News</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Photos</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Videos</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Music</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Tour</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Store</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!--jumbotron-->
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1 class="display-3">Truth Takes Time</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="section-header mt-5 mb-5">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-3x mr-4 mt-2" aria-hidden="true"></i><h4 class="display-4"> Latest News</h4>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-link ml-auto mt-3">View all news   <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>

    <section id="news">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="img/pexels-photo-257909.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Tis the Treason Holiday Bundle</h4>
                        </a>
                        <p class="card-text">We’ve added a few new items the webstore, including this limited Tis the Treason...</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small>November 3, 2017</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="img/pexels-photo-69212.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Vevo "Why I Vote"</h4>
                        </a>
                        <p class="card-text">Tim recently sat down with Vevo to discuss why it's improtant to vote.  Check it out </p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small>October 23, 2017</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="img/pexels-photo-167523.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Synthesis available everywhere now!</h4>
                        </a>
                        <p class="card-text">Our new album, Synthesis, is available everywhere now!</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small>September 12, 2017</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="img/pexels-photo-167580.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h4 class="card-title">2017 Fall Tour</h4>
                        </a>
                        <p class="card-text">We’re hitting the road this Fall for a run of headline dates across the US + Canada with special guests!</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small>August 9, 2017</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section-header mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-camera fa-3x mr-4 mt-2" aria-hidden="true"></i><h4 class="display-4"> Photos</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link ml-auto mt-3">View all pics   <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="picGallery">
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="img/pexels-photo-92080.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="picGallery">
                        <img src="img/pexels-photo-92080.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="img/pexels-photo-167378.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="picGallery">
                        <img src="img/pexels-photo-167378.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="img/pexels-photo-417473.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="picGallery">
                        <img src="img/pexels-photo-417473.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="img/pexels-photo-354304.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="picGallery">
                        <img src="img/pexels-photo-354304.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="img/pexels-photo-167609.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="picGallery">
                        <img src="img/pexels-photo-167609.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="img/pexels-photo-167382.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="picGallery">
                        <img src="img/pexels-photo-167382.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="img/pexels-photo-167466.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="picGallery">
                        <img src="img/pexels-photo-167466.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="img/pexels-photo-141376.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="picGallery">
                        <img src="img/pexels-photo-141376.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section-header mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-3x mr-4 mt-2" aria-hidden="true"></i><h4 class="display-4"> Videos</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link ml-auto mt-3">View all videos   <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="vidGallery">
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6mFF3VmVAs" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos">
                        <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/yP11r5n5RNg/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a href="http://youtu.be/iQ4D273C7Ac" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos">
                        <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/iQ4D273C7Ac/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a href="//www.youtube.com/embed/b0jqPvpn3sY" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos">
                        <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/b0jqPvpn3sY/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a href="http://youtu.be/iQ4D273C7Ac" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos">
                        <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/iQ4D273C7Ac/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6mFF3VmVAs" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos">
                        <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/yP11r5n5RNg/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a href="http://youtu.be/iQ4D273C7Ac" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos">
                        <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/iQ4D273C7Ac/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a href="//www.youtube.com/embed/b0jqPvpn3sY" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos">
                        <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/b0jqPvpn3sY/mqdefault.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="section-header mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fa-3x mr-4 mt-2" aria-hidden="true"></i><h4 class="display-4"> Store</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link ml-auto mt-3">View all merch   <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>




    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9a90c9b9d4.js"></script>
    <!--bootstrap standard Javascript-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--lightbox js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).ekkoLightbox();
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

The only difference is I remove the class="col-md-4" from the default code as my  tag is already in a col-md-3.

Mine comes out looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have additional code? I'm running the code you provided and when I click on the video link, it doesn't open in a modal. It loads a new page with the video.

Comment: I don't have any additional code that I can think of relating to this section. I even started the whole html page over and it still does it.

Comment: You mentioned: "I've implemented the css and the jQuery script at the bottom of my body." I could look at your entire implementation and see if the error is elsewhere.

Comment: okay. Updated original post with full html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is going to be with the iframe looking for the video in the local environment - I am assuming you are developing locally and not serving your file via a server. The iframe will be basically looking for `file://youtube.com/embed/someVideoBlahBlah`. This wiki article talks about it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme. In order to fix the issue you will have to develop via a server. I created a super simple Express server (see code below), ran your code and the videos work perfectly. In other words - your code is fine, it's just the way you are serving your html file that's causing the problem.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path');

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html')))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```